# IE plugin(?)/extension to stop browsing certain websites by time of day

Tags: internet-explorer, ie-extensions

Is there way to prevent this on my computer? I want to limit browsing distracting sites to certain times of the day and it's only for me and a router solution is not possible as it's on laptop used in numerous locations.

I know I can do this on firefox but I'd like to do this on IE.

I suppose I'll have to install local proxserver or simillar?

My current solution is to edit the hosts file - but that need manual maintenance and I would like to avoid that if possible.

Comment: Can you give a bit more info? Sometimes it's better to know the problem then to ask about a solution. Are you trying to block yourself from surfing Facebook too much or are you trying to block your kids surfing after bedtime, etc..? Is a router solution out of the question etc?

Comment: The earler. I want to limit browsing distracting sites to certain times of the day.